# Google Shopping product stars

Tags: google-shopping

I'm trying to show my customers' ratings of products on Google Shopping but I can not do it.

Could someone tell me how I can do this?

I speak of the reviews and the stars that customers leave after buying a product.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get an approved product review company to manage the reviews on your site. You can see more here:

https://support.google.com/merchants/answer/6059553?hl=en-GB

There is a list of supported vendors here:

https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/2375474?hl=en-GB

Note that's for Seller Ratings, as opposed to Product Ratings, but the process is the same.

Matt.

Answer (score 1):

Not directly related to your question but if you need to get reviews from the product programmatically, you can use a third-party API, such as [Google Reviews Results API](https://serpapi.com/reviews-results).

Check code in the [online IDE](https://replit.com/@denisskopa/scrape-google-product-review-raiting-serpapi#main.py) that also paginates through all available reviews from a certain product:

```py
from serpapi import GoogleSearch
from urllib.parse import urlsplit, parse_qsl
import json

params = {
    'api_key': "...",                       # https://serpapi.com/manage-api-key
    'engine': 'google_product',             # SerpApi search engine 
    'product_id': '14019378181107046593',   # product id
    'reviews': True,                        # more reviews, could be also set as '1' which is the same as True
    'hl': 'en',                             # language
    'gl': 'us'                              # country of the search, US -> USA
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)               # where data extraction happens on the backend
results = search.get_dict()                 # JSON -> Python dict

reviews_results = {
    'reviews': results['reviews_results']['reviews']
}

while True:
    if "next" in results.get("serpapi_pagination", {}):
        search.params_dict.update(dict(parse_qsl(urlsplit(results.get("serpapi_pagination", {}).get("next")).query)))
    else:
        break
    
    results = search.get_dict()             # new_page_results
    
    reviews_results['reviews'].extend(results['reviews_results']['reviews'])

print(json.dumps(reviews_results, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False))
print(len(reviews_results['reviews']))
```

Example output:

```json
[
    {
      "position": 2,
      "title": "Good",
      "date": "December 2, 2022",
      "rating": 5,
      "source": "Good · Review provided by bestbuy.com",
      "content": "Good one of good product to buy would love to buy again "
    },
    {
      "position": 3,
      "title": "Jag ärlskar den!",
      "date": "April 27, 2022",
      "rating": 5,
      "source": "kaMs · Review provided by elgiganten.se",
      "content": "Jag köpte den här musen för några veckor sedan och den är så snygg och skön. Knapparna på sidorna är väldigt svåra att vänja sig vid, men dom är sköna att trycka på. Rgb:n är det bästa som finns. "
    }
    other results ...
]
103       # number of reviews is the same as on the Google Product page
```